# Bluetooth connection state problem of Arduino BLE

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

When connected to a Bluetooth device in android os, it is indicated in blue to check the connection status.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2KxM.jpg)

When I paired the Arduino device and launched the app, I connected the GATT and got the signal.

But I don't know why the color of the device doesn't change to blue, and there's a toast saying, "Install the apps you need to use this device."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu1LX.jpg)

Please let me know if there's a solution.

Comment: I know the nrf connect app.
I also checked the Bluetooth connection and signal on the nrf app.
However, it is not possible to check the connected status of android os in the nrf app, either.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You have a BLE device based on an Arduino. You have an App to write and read the characteristics. Now you connect your BLE device to your phone by using the Bluetooth Menu in your phone? That's not needed for a BLE connection and usually not possible, which is weird. BLE and Bluetooth work differently. Could you clarify what software you are running on the arduino and your smartphone? What kind of arduino and which BLE adapter are you using?

Comment: First of all, we are using Arduino's low-power Bluetooth module.
And in the android application, Bluetooth service is executed, connection is checked and signal is received through BluetoothGattCallback function.

But I can't confirm that Bluetooth devices are connected in the cell phone OS.

I wonder if low power Bluetooth is originally impossible to check or if coding is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your problem now. There is no way to see a connected Bluetooth Low Energy device in your phones OS. The OS only displays connected Bluetooth classic devices. These technologies work differently. If you want to display the connection state you need to do it in your app.